# Window Style Resource Does Not Override UserControl Property When Present

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Given I have a control from somewhere called `SomeControl`

In MyUserControl.xaml I use `SomeControl` like so:

```
<Grid.Resources>
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="local:SomeControl">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ToolTip>
          <TextBlock Text="FOO"/>
       </ToolTip>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid>
  <!-- Others controls in here -->
  <local:SomeControl />
</Grid>
```

In Window.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="local:SomeControl">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ToolTip>
          <TextBlock Text="BAR"/>
       </ToolTip>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <local:MyUserControl />
</Grid>
```

The result is it will display `Foo` when I want it to display `Bar`.
If I delete the ToolTip from the UserControl, the Window's style is used and it displays `Bar` like I expect.

Why is the Window style not overriding the UserControl explicit ToolTip property when present, but does when removed?

For the record, I've also tried changing MyUserControl to use a DynamicResource of the same `x:Key` names and had no affect.

Changing both to ToolTipService.ToolTip also had the same results.

EDIT: I fixed the example to demonstrate that even if the ToolTip is not set on a local level, it still doesn't override the style.

Comment: why is your style targeting SomeControl, but your control is named MyUserControl?

Comment: Because the type inside the user control is `SomeControl`. I'm not trying to target `MyUserControl`, I'm trying to target `SomeControl`.

`Window` has a `UserControl` which has a `SomeControl` The ToolTip is on `SomeControl` and not `UserControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone can answer how to do override the children's style for the tooltip, I ended up making ToolTip object a dependency property on `MyUserControl` and passing it down to `SomeControl`.

The dependency property I made is called `ExampleToolTip`

MyUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name='MainControl'>
  <UserControl.Resources>
   <ToolTip x:Key="DefaultSomeControlToolTip">
      <TextBlock Text="FOO"/>
   <ToolTip>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <local:SomeControl ToolTip="{Binding ExampleToolTip, ElementName=MainControl, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultSomeControlToolTip}}"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window.xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <local:MyUserControl>
     <local:MyUserControl.ExampleToolTip>
       <ToolTip>
          <TextBlock Text="BAR"/>
       </ToolTip>
     </local:MyUserControl.ExampleToolTip>
  </local:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

Now I can use `MyUserControl` with it's special "FOO" tooltip on `SomeControl` and `Window` has its "BAR" tooltip overriding it.

Comment: As far as I know (and from testing), it doesn't drill down the visual tree. It only applies it to the top level control and if the control is in a container like for a ListBoxItem, you can do what you are trying to do. You can see this if you stick a TextBlock and a Button on a dialog and try to apply a font weight to the TextBlock type. Only the actual TextBlock type will pick it up. The TextBlock within the button doesn't.